# function with vectors which is part of a class is not working and no compiler errors

Tags: c++, string, function, variables, vector

So, I have a member function (show_players_names and show_players_levels) of a class which prints on the screen the value of a private variable.

Although the compiler doesn't show any error, I do not see the names and the levels on the screen.

Do you have any idea?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Party {
    private:
        string boss;
        vector<string> players;
        vector<int> players_level;

    public:
        string party_name;  

    Party (string party_name, string boss)  { cout << party_name << " " << boss << endl; };  
    ~Party() { cout << "Party delete" << endl; };   


    vector<string> getNames() { return players; };
    vector<int> getLevels() { return players_level; };

    vector<string> setNames (const vector<string> &new_players) { players=new_players; }
    vector<int> setLevels (const vector<int> &new_players_level) { players_level=new_players_level; 
};


 void show_players_names()
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<players.size(); i++ )
            cout << players[i] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    };

    void show_players_levels()
    {
        for(size_t i=0; i<players_level.size(); ++i )
            cout << players_level[i] <<' ';
        cout << endl;
    };

};

int main ()
{
    Party party1("Witchers","Vesemir");

    party1.setNames({"Gerald","Eskel","Lambert"});
    party1.setLevels( {50,45,49} );
    party1.show_players_names();
    party1.show_players_levels();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get two warnings when I compile this. Do you not get the warnings? `vesimir.cpp:25:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: You need a better C++ compiler, that will actually tell you what's the problem with the shown code. If your compiler did warn you about problems with your code, this is a good learning opportunity: never ignore warning messages from your compiler, even if it ended up compiling the code in the end. Those warning messages are there fore a reason. So, did you compiler show you any warning messages, or not?

Comment: @JohnFilleau No, I do not get these warnings when comliped, sorry...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik no there was no warning messages from the compiler.

Comment: @S.M. Well, thank you, I'm still learning. Never said it is the best code written.

Comment: What compiler are you using? For compiler name `compiler`, you should do a search with your favorite search engine for "`compiler` turn on all warnings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
vector<string> setNames (const vector<string> &new_players) { 
    players=new_players;
}
vector<int> setLevels (const vector<int> &new_players_level) { 
    players_level=new_players_level; 
}
```

is wrong as there's no return statement.
Changing the declaration of the methods to `void` makes the code working as expected.

```
void setNames (const vector<string> &new_players) { 
    players=new_players;
}
void setLevels (const vector<int> &new_players_level) { 
    players_level=new_players_level; 
}
```

For reasons not entirely clear to me omitting a return statement in a non-void function on many compilers is not a fatal compile error (what I think it should be) and is instead just a warning, but the generated code has undefined behavior (with g++ for example your code segfaults).

When you execute code containing UB anything can happen, including working apparently but with strange behavior.